# Iterator style c++

Tags: c++

When is it better to declare the iterator? This is some example code taken from cprogramming.com just to illistrate what I'm referring to.

inside the for loop?

```
for(vector<int>::iterator myIntVectorIterator = myIntVector.begin(); 
        myIntVectorIterator != myIntVector.end();
        myIntVectorIterator++)
{
    cout<<*myIntVectorIterator<<" ";
}
```

or outside the for loop?

```
vector<int>::iterator myIntVectorIterator;

for(myIntVectorIterator = myIntVector.begin(); 
        myIntVectorIterator != myIntVector.end();
        myIntVectorIterator++)
{
    cout<<*myIntVectorIterator<<" ";
}
```

Comment: In a descent compiler it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: For iterators, use `auto` (not what you are asking, just saying...).

Comment: @hyde C++11 is great that way.

Comment: Compiler-wise, it does not make a difference. Use whatever's more readable; in any case, go for `myVector::iterator`, not `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: It's a matter of style. Personally I usually prefer it in the loop, because I generally think of the iterator as being associated with the loop. You can do it either way, though.

Comment: Its a matter of coding style - prefer right before usage in the most inner scope.

Comment: i'd prefer putting it inside the loop

Comment: @40two Never knew [descent](http://www.interplay.com/games/descent.php) had it's own compiler. ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator my bad :) one letter makes a difference after all...

Answer (score 6):

There's almost no functional difference between either of those styles. Choose the one that makes your code the most readable.

Alternatively, C++ 2011 includes a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) that is much more readable than either of those options:

```
for (int & element : myIntVector) {
    cout << element << " ";
}
```

Comment: Unless of course you are dealing with fat iterators, which are troubling enough in any case.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I haven't heard of the term "fat iterator" before. Do you have a link describing it? And either way, the only issue here is if the default constructor is expensive (or if the `operator=` is more expensive than the equivalent constructor).

Comment: input iterators are an example of a fat iterator (and a bad idea). In general, it just means they are uncommonly expensive to copy / assign and might have weird behavior on construction.

Answer (score 5):

Typical practice is to declare all variables in the same scope where they`ll be used. Following this principle, you should declare your iterator variable inside the loop declaration.

As commenters have noted, it's not *wrong* to declare the iterator outside the loop, but I can think of a few reasons why it's not a good idea.

- **It makes the code less readable.** This is always a matter of opinion, but in my experience, people looking at your code would see your iterator declared at the start of the function, and would spend extra time trying to find where it gets used, wasting a "brain cycle" on a question with no answer. I'll admit that this is kind of a petty complaint, but as your code grows in complexity I find you generally want to make understanding it as easy as possible.
- **It doesn't do anything there.** Sort of related to the above, loop iterators don't usually have any context outside of the loop they're related to. If you're not going to use the value again, why make it available outside the loop?
- **It makes your code less maintainable.** If you only have a small number of loops this argument falls apart, but it means that you now have to expend another brain cycle when you're modifying your code: "which loop did this variable belong to again?" kind of deal. Like my first point this is a petty concern, but again I've found that minimizing the amount of time yo have to think about code (even if it's only a small gain) goes a long way.

Of course, as many others have noted, there's no practical difference between the two approaches, and you may have use-cases that make it relevant or necessary, or it may just be a matter of style. If you can possibly avoid it, though, I would advise not declaring loop iterators at a higher scope than the loop.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on what scope you want the iterator to have. Generally speaking, you want to restrict its scope as much as possible while still letting it to its job<sup>1</sup>.

If you're only going to use it inside the body of the loop, then it's preferable to define it in the loop header, so its scope is restricted to the loop body.

If you're going to use it after the end of the loop, then define it above the loop so it still exists after the end of the loop.

Of course, you generally want to avoid the whole question, such as by using a standard algorithm or range-based for loop (usually with `auto` instead of specifying the type explicitly).

---

<sub>1. The same applies in general, not just to iterators.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

According to the C++ Standard the for statement

for ( for-init-statement conditionopt; expressionopt) statement

is equivalent to

```
{
   for-init-statement

   while ( condition ) 
   {
      statement; 
      expression;
   }
}
```

As you see the `for_init-statment`  is executed only once. Applied to ypur for-statement it will look as

```
{
   vector<int>::iterator myIntVectorIterator = myIntVector.begin();

   while ( myIntVectorIterator != myIntVector.end() )
   {
      cout<<*myIntVectorIterator<<" ";
      myIntVectorIterator++;
   {
}
```

So if myIntVectorIterator need not to be used after the loop in some other code segment there is no any sense to define it  outside the scope of the loop.

Take also into account that the complexity of the creating of the iterator is constant ( O(1) ) and does not depend on the size of the container.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of compactness i would use inside the loop variant.

Comment: Better as a comment...